# changes in views of index.pug file are not reloading live or after refresh using nodemon while running in node.js in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, pug, nodemon

I searched this issue but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798788/change-jade-always-require-node-js-restart-then-can-verify-the-change) did not solve my problem.

whenever I make changes in app.js, then they don't seen in browser. 
nodemon doesn't work, it just shows output in terminal as `[nodemon] restarting due to changes..` but not "actually" refreshing.

I start my app.js using `npm start` and start script is `"start": "nodemon -e js, pug"`, even when I manually run `nodemon app.js` then only it doesnot refreshes automatically and dynamically.

I am fetching data from MongoDB and have used mongoose.

app.js works perfect when I stop nodemon by `CTRL+C` and `npm start`, but not hot reloading.

is this problem of my template engine-pug.js?

Answer (score 3):

Drop the space, you should run `nodemon -e js,pug` as nodemon is parsing the arguments using spaces, so it's seeing the extensions as "js" and not "js and pug".

That should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, Remy, it helped but it is refreshing only  .pug files, not main app.js.     
to refresh app.js file I have to manually do it to bring changes

Comment: @GD-GaneshDeshmukh, you can include `app.js` in the `watch`.  For ex:

`nodemon -w app.js -w my-pug-file.pug -e js,pug --exec node.js`

Comment: @Aakash, will try that, as of now same setup is not available... thanks for that.