# Why my html content not update without restart javascript server?

Tags: html, node.js, updating

I am learning about NodeJS and I am using simple code for tests. My problem is I must restart server for each change I realize to my code but I see videos where another developers to make changes on html file and they must not restart server.
What I do incorrect?
Thank you!

package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xxxxxx",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "xxxxxxxx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine','pug');
let personas = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: 'wwww'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nombre: 'qqqq'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nombre: 'ssss'
  }
];
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.render('index',{hola:"Hola wqw",titulo:'pug',mensaje:'sdasd!!',personas:personas});
  //res.send('Hola mundo');
});
app.listen(8080);
```

index.pug

```
html
  head
    title= titulo
    link(href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css',rel='stylesheet')
  body
    div.container
      h1= mensaje
      table.table.table-striped
        for persona in personas
          tr
            td= persona.id
            td
              a(href='/persona/' + persona.id) #{persona.nombre}
      - //Esto se ejecuta en el servidor
      - var arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5];
      - for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++)
        p= arreglo[i]
      p!= "<h1>Se ejecuta como HTML</h1>"
      p Hola #{mensaje}
      p.
        Hola haz click en #[a(href="https://www.google.com") este link]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798788/change-jade-always-require-node-js-restart-then-can-verify-the-change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get your server to automatically update, you have to install the right package. For example the npm package nodemon.
npm install -g nodemon(or if yarn, use that command) will install the package globally so you can have your servers autorestart. Instead of the command "node app" you would then use the command "nodemon app".
Hope this answers your question!